# Run and close a file every few minutes

Tags: debian, cron, scheduling

I need to play an audio file and after 3 minutes close it, then all over again. play it 3 minutes and close it.

Currently I'm using a cron job to open the file in VLC and close it, but it's not good enough as it goes out of sync every once in a while.

Is there any alternative to this task with using a cron job?

```
*/3 * * * * cvlc /home/pi/Downloads/buildm3u
*/3 * * * * sleep 178; pkill vlc
```

Comment: use just one cronjob with `timeout 178 cvlc ...`.

Comment: Is the audio file only 3 minutes long? Or is it longer and you just want to play 3 minutes of it?

Comment: It's a streaming file so it's basically endless.

Comment: Hi @RoVo, it seems that the command is ignored. 
" */3 * * * * timeout -s 2 180 python3 /home/pi/test.py "

and also I tried:
" */3 * * * * timeout 180 python3 /home/pi/test.py "

I'm testing it with a python script, and it seems it just keeps running.